# DatePicker for WatchOS2?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

There's any way of achieving this in watchOS2 easily?

The only workaround I have so far is building it manually using three `WKInterfacePicker`s.

Answer (score 0):

Well..it looks like there are no workarounds... I have created a Date of Birth Selection view and uploaded it into [this project at GitHub](https://github.com/halonsoluis/WatchOS2DatePicker).

> I did set the maximum lifespan for this example into **150 years**...hopely I will have the need to expand it any time soon. :-)

Comment: Did you find a way to localize the order of the individual pickers (in a vertical group), e.g. MDY vs. DMY vs. YMD?

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this objC version of TimePicker and DatePicker on github which may be useful:

https://github.com/rrramanan/WatchOS2-DatePicker

https://github.com/rrramanan/WatchOS2-TimePicker